# Binary Random Number

Tags: java

I have a situation where I need t generate 16 unique random sequence of 50- bit binary numbers. And then store it in a 4x4 matrix into a file.

I have done it in this manner

```
import java.util.Random; 
public class BitGenerator{ 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
 String bits = ""; 
 Random r = new Random(); 
 for(int j=0; j<15; j++){ 
   for(int i=0; i<50; i++){ 
     int x = 0; 
     if(r.nextBoolean()) x=1; 
     bits += x; 
   }
  }
 System.out.println(bits); 
} 
}
```

but when I am running this program, "java BitGenerator > Random.doc", its showing all the characters in one go. Please help.

Comment: Do you add C tag everywhere you see a curly brace?

Comment: Why are you writing 15 not 16 lots of 50 bit random numbers without any formatiing on one line?  This is just the same as printing 15*50 = 750 random bits. Where does the 4x4 come into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using booleans you can use bitwise operations (see Jack's answer) to extract a random binary value and insert it into a string matrix. Here is a [live](https://ideone.com/tqh4Ag) example.

```
final Random r = new Random();
String matrix[][] = new String[4][4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
        long value = r.nextLong() >>> -50;
        value |= 1L << 50;
        matrix[i][j] = Long.toBinaryString(value).substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. But unfortunately I can't store it in a matrix of 4x4.

Comment: @KrishnenduRarhi What do you mean by a 4x4 matrix? Do you want four rows separated by newlines and four columns separated by blankspaces? Something like [this](https://ideone.com/Gde9TT)?

Comment: No. not exactly. I want each randomly generated 50 bit binary number to be an element of the 4x4 matrix. Like a[0][0] of 50 bits, a[0][1] of 50 bits, a[0][2] of 50 bits, .... a[1][0] of 50 bits, a[1][1] of 50 bits, ... and so on till a[4][4] of 50 bits.

Comment: @KrishnenduRarhi Alright, see my updated answer and remember to tick the green check if helped you :)

Comment: This one really worked. Thanks a lot for your generous help.

Comment: @KrishnenduRarhi There is no *binary data type* in Java unless you're referring to store the variable as an long where each bit is presented with a 0 or 1. You could also store it in a `byte[]` datatype if that's what you mean.

Comment: Extremely sorry to bother you once again. I want to store the binary elements in a binary data type matrix, and not as a string type matrix. Is there any provision for this? As I can store binary numbers like "int x=0b101", similary how can I store all the binary elements in a binary matrix, which I further want to operate on it.;

Comment: @KrishnenduRarhi You'd have to use a `long` because in java an `int` is only 32 bits and you need 50 bits.

Comment: @KrishnenduRarhi [Here](https://ideone.com/tqh4Ag) is how you can store the random binary elements in a `long` matrix and print each bit individually.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just generate a 64 bit random number and then mask it to get only the least significative 50 bits? [Something like](http://ideone.com/5TLiGh):

```
final Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
  long value = r.nextLong() & 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFL;
  String stringValue = Long.toBinaryString(value);
  // pad stringValues with 0s if length < 50
  // or set to 1 the 51th bit and then trim first character

  // output number on file
}
```

To force the string to be 50 chars you can use a sort of hack, set 51th bit and then discard first character, something like:

```
value |= 1L << 50;
String stringValue = Long.toBinaryString(value).substring(1);
```

Comment: BTW to keep 50 bits you can write `r.nextLong() >>> -50` ;)